# AHK "PixelGetColor" Constantly Returning True

Tags: autohotkey

For starters, I'm really new to AutoHotKey. I was making a script that looks for a color (with a little variance) at a specific coordinate, & if it finds that color, type the specified number.

It should continuously sift through the five coordinate spots in the loop and send the number that matches the color, but it finds the number every single time. Just a constant stream of "123451234512345" I've tried completely removing the color from the screen, but it still manages to find it.

I'm sure that I probably have something wrong with my code. Getting a headache trying to figure out what. Would love some help.

```
    Loop
    {   
        CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
        PixelGetColor, color1x, color1y, 200, 200, 200, 200, 0xFF0000, 3, FastRGB
        if ErrorLevel = 0
            Send, 1
        else
        
        CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
        PixelGetColor, color2x, color2y, 400, 400, 400, 400, 0xFF0000, 3, FastRGB
        if ErrorLevel = 0
            Send, 2
        else
        
        CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
        PixelGetColor, color3x, color3y, 600, 600, 600, 600, 0xFF0000, 3, FastRGB
        if ErrorLevel = 0
            Send, 3
        else
        
        CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
        PixelGetColor, color4x, color4y, 800, 800, 800, 800, 0xFF0000, 3, FastRGB
        if ErrorLevel = 0
            Send, 4
        else
        
        CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
        PixelGetColor, color5x, color5y, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 0xFF0000, 3, FastRGB
        if ErrorLevel = 0
            Send, 5
        else
        
return
}
Numpad9::pause
esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: See the documentation for `PixelGetColor` again. There is no such mode as `Fast` and modes would need to be separated by spaces. You should also specify CoordMode only once at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are wrong with your code:

1. You're using `PixelGetColor` incorrectly. It stores the color of the pixel at the desired coordinates in `OutputVar`, not compare the color of the pixel at that coordinate with a specified color.
2. You're checking the `ErrorLevel`. It's set to 1 if there's a problem or 0 otherwise.
3. If you need to scan the five locations for each loop, there's no need for the `else` statement (you're also using it incorrectly in this case).
4. As what 0x464e said, you need to state `CoordMode` only once at the start of the script.

In your case, `PixelGetColor` always succeeds in getting the color of the pixel, which means `ErrorLevel` is always set to zero. This gives you the impression that it's always "returning true".
You should be checking  the `OutputVar` instead. Try this:

```
DESIRED_COLOR := "0xFF0000"
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen

Loop
{   
    PixelGetColor, color1, 200, 200
    if (color1 = DESIRED_COLOR)
        Send, 1
           
    PixelGetColor, color2, 400, 400
    if (color2 = DESIRED_COLOR)
        Send, 2
    
    PixelGetColor, color3, 600, 600
    if (color3 = DESIRED_COLOR)
        Send, 3

    PixelGetColor, color4, 800, 800
    if (color4 = DESIRED_COLOR)
        Send, 4

    PixelGetColor, color5, 1000, 1000
    if (color5 = DESIRED_COLOR)
        Send, 5
}

Numpad9::pause
esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I totally got it confused for PixelSearch. Tacked on RGB at the end of the coordinates and it worked flawlessly.